# Extracting dates from long filename

Tags: r, regex, extract, filenames

I've read through some of the other questions on here about extracting dates (or different sections) from filenames, but I can't seem to get any of the other answers to work on my filenames.
I have a list of >15,000 filenames from a directory and I need to extract the dates from the filenames so I can then figure out which dates I am missing (I should have 15,706 in total, but in some dirs. I only have ~15,600)

Here's an example

```
maxTemps <- list.files("./Daily/Daily_TMax/", recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".asc$", full.names = FALSE)
length(maxTemps)
[1] 15697

head(maxTemps)
[1] "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700101.asc" "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700102.asc"
[3] "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700103.asc" "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700104.asc"
[5] "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700105.asc" "1970/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_19700106.asc"

tail(maxTemps)
[1] "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121226.asc" "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121227.asc"
[3] "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121228.asc" "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121229.asc"
[5] "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121230.asc" "2012/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_20121231.asc"
```

I've been able to use the following code to get the years (based on the folder)

```
regmatches(maxTemp, regexpr("[0-9]{4}", maxTemp))
```

I thought I could use this, with `invert = TRUE` to return the rest of the strings because if I try to include the constant part of the filename in the `regexpr` I get an error

```
maxTempsFiles <- regmatches(maxTemp, regexpr("[0-9]{4}\/(eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_)", maxTemp), invert = TRUE)
Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""[0-9]{4}\/"
```

So I thought I could use the code that works and then subset out the constant part of the filename leaving me with the date, and then I would just need to remove the .asc with `sub`, but this returns some messy text

```
maxTempsFiles <- regmatches(maxTemp, regexpr("[0-9]{4}", maxTemp), invert = TRUE)
maxTempsFiles <- sub(x = maxTempsFiles, pattern = "/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_tmax_v1m0_", replacement = "")
maxTempsFiles <- sub(x = maxTempsFiles, pattern = ".asc", replacement = "")
head(maxTempsFiles)
[1] "c(\"\", \"19700101\")" "c(\"\", \"19700102\")" "c(\"\", \"19700103\")" "c(\"\", \"19700104\")" "c(\"\", \"19700105\")"
[6] "c(\"\", \"19700106\")"
```

The files always have `/eMAST_ANUClimate_day_prec_v1m0_` in them, it is just the first folder which changes, and the end of the filename `19700101.asc` through to `20121231.asc`

If someone could provide some code/advice on how best to do this, that'd be great.

Comment: How about `gsub("(^.*_)(\\d+)\\.asc", "\\2", x)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwer @RomanLuštrik. I haven't had much experience with `gsub`, `sub`, `regexpr` etc before.
Could you place your comment in an answer @RomanLuštrik, to explain exactly what it does? I'm trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple searching for partial matches of the string using groups - and returning the desired match in a group.

```
gsub("(^.*_)(\\d+)\\.asc$", "\\2", x)
```

Regex explanation:

```
group 1:
  (^.*_) - match beginning of string (^) and then any character until _ is found
group 2:
  (\\d+) - find any digit, several times (+)
no group:
  \\.asc$ - at last, find .asc, which should be the end of the string ($)
```

`replacement` argument in `gsub` is there to replace matched part of the string, or, return a desired group. For group 2, you will want `\\2`. Difference between `sub` and `gsub` is that former will return only first matched pattern while `gsub` will work on the entire vector.